# How to write a procedure to create table by inputting a variable date?

Tags: mysql, procedure, create-table

## Goal

I want to create table as follow, the format of table name is `tbl`+`_`+`date` , but I want to write a procedure to create when I input a given date.

```
drop table if exists tbl_20200802 ;
create table tbl_20200802 (index (USERID) )
select * from a;
```

## Try

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS pro_ljj_push_pre_id;
CREATE PROCEDURE pro_ljj_push_pre_id(
    IN test_date date
)
BEGIN
set @table_name=CONCAT('tbl_', test_date);


SET @t1 =CONCAT(
                            'drop table if exists '
                                ,@table_name 
                                ,';'
                                ,'\n'
                                ,'create table ', tab_name
                                , ' (index (USERID))'
                                ,'\n'
                                ,'SELECT * FROM a');
 PREPARE stmt3 FROM @t1;
 EXECUTE stmt3;
 DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt3;
-- 
END //
DELIMITER ;

CALL pro_ljj_push_pre_id('20200802');
```

> 1054 - Unknown column 'tab_name' in 'field list'

Comment: Don't do it!  This seems like a really bad database design.  Put all the data in one table with a date column.

Comment: What is `tab_name` supposed to be? It's not declared anywhere.

Comment: @stickybit the format of table_name is 'tbl_'+date. The tab_name is set by@table_name

Comment: `tab_name` isn't set anywhere (to anything)  as far as I can see. It just appears in the second `concat()`.

Comment: @stickybit yes, it is

Comment: OK, then I just might be blind. I cannot see it. (But you may give me hint...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some syntax error in your code,
However, the following is your desired. Change the structure of table as you want.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS pro_ljj_push_pre_id$$
CREATE PROCEDURE pro_ljj_push_pre_id(IN test_date VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
set @table_name=CONCAT('tbl_', test_date);

 SET @t1 =CONCAT('drop table if exists ',@table_name);
 SELECT @t1;
 PREPARE stmt3 FROM @t1;
 EXECUTE stmt3;
 DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt3;
 SET @t2 =CONCAT('create table ', @table_name, ' (id INT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(30));');
 SELECT @t2;
 PREPARE stmt4 FROM @t2;
 EXECUTE stmt4;
 DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt4;
-- 
END $$
DELIMITER ;

CALL pro_ljj_push_pre_id('20200802');
```